# Get Cart Id from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I need to capture the cartID in a js variable from a JSON response.

So far I have the following code which requests the cart information.

```js
function getCart(url) {
   return fetch(url, {
       method: "GET",
       credentials: "same-origin"
   })
   .then(response => response.json())
};

var cartID = 'unknown';

getCart('/api/storefront/carts')
.then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The console.log data is formatted like this:

```js
Extract of full data:
[{"id":"c5f24d63-cd9a-46f2-be41-6ad31fc38b51","customerId":1,"email":"me@gmail.com", ................. }]
```

I have tried various methods to capture the cart ID to variable cartID, but each time it shows 'unknown' and is logged before the data response.

Any ideas how to delay until the response is ready and then 'cartID' with the id value?

Comment: What did you get when you try this `data[0].cartID`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Also relevant: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: @HassanImam console shows: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Looks like your `data` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Because the response if a JSON array, you can try to loop and extract the cartID from each cart object:

```
function getCart(url) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
 };
 
 var cartID = 'unknown';
 
 getCart('/api/storefront/carts')
 .then(
     data => {
         //The response is an array of cart objects. We need to extract the ID from the array
         cartID = data[0].id;

         //Or loop through the response and extract the ID from each cart object
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             cartID = data[i].id;
         }
     }
     )
 .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but the console shows:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')